# node.js no interaction with child using child_process

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, child-process

All,

Trying to use node.js to isolate JS plugins created by others through the child_process API in node.js. I can't get the child process to interact with the parent, I get no errors running this code but the client can't send or receive messages, or write to console.log, so I assume the JS isn't running. I do get a console message that the debugger is running from both the parent as well as the client. Code is pretty much straight out of the node.js API docs so I'm not sure why this won't work. Perhaps something wrong with the Windows environment?

parent code:

```
var fork = require('child_process').fork;

console.log('Starting plugin server...');

var myChild = fork('client.js');

myChild.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log('PARENT got message:', msg)
});

myChild.send({ hello: 'world' });
```

client.js:

```
console.log("child");

process.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log('CHILD got message:', msg)
    process.send({msg: 'Message receivd & resent from the child.'})
});

process.send({msg: 'Message from the child.'});
```

Output:

```
debugger listening on port 5858
Starting plugin server...
debugger listening on port 5858
```

I'm using Windows 8.1, visual studio 2013 pro with the new tools for node.js add-ins.

Any pointers appreciated. I'm new to node.js so possibly making a silly mistake??

Comment: OK, getting a little further here. It seems it is the visual studio environment or the node.js tools for VS. When running the application without the debugger (ctrl-F5) I get the right behaviour. Possibly something to do with the child using the same debug TCP port, or the VS debugger getting confused when 2 instances of node are running.

It's still a problem as I need to be able to debug the plugins, but will try the remote debugger option in VS node.JS tools. Having the same debug port for both the parent & child is going to be a problem I guess, and the VS node.js tools can't change ports.

Answer (score 1):

I had problem with fork() on windows machines. Solution/workaround was with silent mode and logging. Here is link https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/1516

Comment: Thanks kraag22, although it's not the same problem (which is related to debugging using the visual studio node.js tools alpha), your link is a useful reference, thanks.